# How to get all test cases from test suite in VSTS without run data

Tags: rest, azure-devops

I'm trying to get all the test cases from a test suite in VSTS, even test cases that have no run data, marked as "Active." I know how to get the case ID, but not the name/title. Right now it goes through the run data and results and gets all the information from the result, but it won't work if there is no run data.

I'm working in C# using RestSharp for RestRequests. This is one of my RestRequests: `/_apis/test/runs?planId=" + planID.ToString() + "&includeRunDetails=true&api-version=5.0-preview.2` This works to get all the information I need for test cases with run data. I have been using Microsoft docs on VSTS API for help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-5.0

Getting the test cases from the suite would be ideal, but I'll accept anything that works.

Comment: More information is needed... are doing this in F#? Do you have a sample of code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I'm working in C# using RestSharp for RestRequests. This is one of my RestRequests: 
/_apis/test/runs?planId=" + planID.ToString() + "&includeRunDetails=true&api-version=5.0-preview.2
This works to get all the information I need for test cases with run data.
I have been using Microsoft docs on VSTS API for help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-5.0

Comment: Could you edit your question and everything in it? It will be easier for people to provide you with an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [Get all test cases in a suite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/test%20%20suites/get%20test%20cases?view=vsts-rest-5.0) api and [Returns a list of work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/list?view=vsts-rest-5.0) api. First, get the test case ids from the api below:

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/test/Plans/{planId}/suites/{suiteId}/testcases?api-version=5.0-preview.3
```

Then, get more information of the test cases from the following api:

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems?ids={ids}&api-version=5.0-preview.3
```